# what does "timid “2.0” ways" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Admittedly, there are a hundred thousand ways you can write a headline to communicate the same message. There’s the uber-awesome Caples-esque Upworthy way. There are simpler, more timid “2.0” ways. There are flashy direct response-style ways. And then there’s everything in between. Yes, this headline could have been wrong. (That’s why we test!) But it didn’t hurt conversion; it just didn’t nudge enough people over the Game of Thrones-sized Wall keeping them from converting.

what does "timid “2.0” ways" mean?

Is it mean two simpler way?

source: http://copyhackers.com/2014/09/buttons-vs-headlines/

Comment: @apsillers I add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a reference to [Web 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0), which was a way of marketing a load of new internet technologies to the public back in 2004. When Web 2.0 was a popular marketing term, a lot of websites had a certain style (search Google Images for 'Web 2.0 website', then compare it with the images you get when you search for 'Web 1.0 website'). When he talks about the "simpler, more timid 2.0" headlines, he's describing the clean and simple (but outdated) style of headline-writing that was popular in 2004.